# QPushButton, to disable all other push buttons unless pressed again

Tags: python, python-3.x, delay, raspberry-pi3, qpushbutton

I have 4 push buttons (open outer, close outer, open inner, close inner) which control 2 doors (via 2 relays), an inner and an outer door. Only one door can be open at a time, I have got this much of the code sorted, now the issue is when I close the outer door I would like it to disable all the other push buttons except for the "open" outer door button. Is this possible? I will paste the relevant section of my code below:

```
 #@QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def OuterDoorOpen(self):
        if Door2_Channel == 0:
            return GPIO.output(self.Door1,GPIO.HIGH)
        else:
            return "Please Close Inner Door"

    #@QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def OuterDoorClose(self):
        if Door2_Channel == 1:
            return
                GPIO.output(self.Door2,GPIO.LOW), self.pushButton_2.setEnabled(False),
self.pushButton_3.setEnabled(False),
self.pushButton_4.setEnabled(False)


    #@QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def InnerDoorOpen(self):
        if Door1_Channel == 0:
            return GPIO.output(self.Door2,GPIO.HIGH)
        else:
            return "Please Close Outer Door"

    #@QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def InnerDoorClose (self):
        if Door1_Channel == 1:
            return GPIO.output(self.Door2,GPIO.LOW)
```

I have designed the GUI using QtDesigner and Im using pyqt5 on python 3.7. I am controlling the relays using a raspberry pi. Whenever I run this code and hit the pushbutton close it causes the programme to crash.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i managed to get this to work by using partials and setting the SetEnabled to False. Here is the relevant section of the code.

```
def OuterDoorClose(self):
    if GPIO.input(Outer)==0: #Outer Door Open
        self.ui.pushButton_3.setEnabled(False)
        self.ui.pushButton_4.setEnabled(False)
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(10000,partial(self.ui.pushButton_3.setEnabled,True))
        return GPIO.output(Outer,GPIO.HIGH)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if the suggestion sounds silly, but what if you add a Try except block within the OuterDoorClose block, and debug your code? It might help you understand which line of code is causing the program to crash and why. Eg:

```
self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
self.timer.timeout.connect(self.enable_buttons)

#@QtCore.pyqtSlot()
def OuterDoorClose(self):
    try:
        if Door2_Channel == 1:
            self.pushButton_2.setEnabled(False)
            self.pushButton_3.setEnabled(False)
            self.pushButton_4.setEnabled(False)
            self.timer.start(30000)
            return GPIO.output(self.Door2,GPIO.LOW)
    except Exception as e:
        #Your exception code



def self.enable_buttons(self):
    self.pushButton_2.setEnabled(True)
    self.pushButton_3.setEnabled(True)
    self.pushButton_4.setEnabled(True)
```

Comment: Hello @Chaitanya Bangera, I know the problem lies in that section of the code which you highlighted as when it is removed the programme runs completely fine.

Comment: Alright, and do you know what the exception is? Also, I was wondering if there is a need to return the setEnabled statements? Will it work if you disable the buttons before returning the values? I have changed the code to reflect what I am trying to say.

Comment: I dont receive an exception message, I get "Backend terminated (returncode: -6)  the GUI just closes down any time the push button is pressed. What I want is when pushButton_2 is clicked, for it to disable all the buttons for say 30 seconds except pushButton_1 which can be clicked to open the door and enable all the buttons again. I hope that makes sense?

Comment: @AlmaasShah Have you executed it from the CMD or terminal or are you using any IDE?

Comment: @eyllanesc I am executing it using Thonny on Raspberry Pi

Comment: ok, I have managed to disable the pushbuttons, I needed to use self.ui.pushButton_3.setEnabled(False) but now how do i do this for 30 second before enabling them again? whenever i use time.sleep(30) it just delays the disabling for 30 seconds.

Comment: You can use Qt's QTimer to run the timer on a separate thread. I have edited my code above. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: @ChaitanyaBangera Thankyou, but no this did not do what I wanted. I simply want to disable a pushbutton then make it clickable again after a certain time. Also I am no longer receiving an exception.

Comment: I managed to solve it. I added this line of code. QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(30000,partial(self.ui.pushButton_3.setEnabled, True))

Comment: In thinking I solved it i've encountered another issue, if i open the door during the 30 seconds then press close again the timer doesn't reset, any ideas? @ChaitanyaBangera

Comment: @AlmaasShah  many IDES as the one you point out do not handle some error messages and only say: *... terminated (returncode: xxx) ...*, so in those cases I recommend using the terminal since there you will get more information.

Comment: @eyllanesc Thankyou